# Examples of continua that are contractible but are not locally connected at any point

Tags: gn.general-topology, examples, continuum-theory

A continuum is a compact, connected, metrizable space.

What are examples of continua that are contractible but nowhere locally connected, meaning that no point has a neighbourhood basis consisting of connected sets?

The following is an example of a contractible nowhere locally connected metrizable space, but I'm not aware of any compact examples (every segment on the "main line" has segments sticking out on a dense set).

[image: the infinite infinite comb]

This question was previously asked on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4419849/examples-of-continua-that-are-contractible-but-are-not-locally-connected-at-any) but didn't get an answer there.

Answer (score 8):

An example of such a space was constructed by Edwards in "R. Edwards, A contractible, nowhere locally connected compactum, Abstracts A.M.S. 20 1999), 494.". The example is the following space:

Start with the space $X$ obtained stacking a sequence of Cantor fans (cones over the Cantor set) end to end as depicted.

[image]

Then consider the space $X\times\Bbb R$, which looks like the upper half-plane with a lot of "fins" attached to it. Let $X'$ be the one point compactification of $X\times\Bbb R$, so that it looks like a closed disk with a lot of circular fins attached. The space $X'$ is a contractible continuum and it is locally connected precisely on the boundary of the circle. To make it nowhere locally connected construct $Y$ from $X'$ by wrapping one more Cantor fan around the circle, the resulting space is still contractible as explained [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419972/why-is-this-space-contractible) and clearly nowhere locally connected (in fact it is also nowhere connected im kleinen).

Now I'm wondering whether a planar contractible continuum must be locally connected somewhere, but that should be a separate question.

Comment: This is a great example. I think it's worth noting that the contraction is not completely obvious. One cannot just contract the fan-surfaces onto the disk. It seems necessary to use the fact that a cone is well-pointed at its vertex. This allows one to put a sliver of surface between each of the fan surfaces in a way that does not change homotopy type. Then collapsing each of the fan-surfaces to a single circle will be a homotopy equivalence. After that one can perform the rotation contraction of the disk and the outer fan described in the other MO post.

Comment: I like it so much I illustrated it in 3-space here: https://wildtopology.com/bestiary/edwards-continuum/

Comment: @JeremyBrazas Those are some beautiful images! How did you generate them? Unrelated but I'm glad you wrote a blog post about this space, now I can keep postponing to "tomorrow" the topology blog I've been meaning to start writing for years!

Comment: Thanks! I worked out the transformational geometry to plot the various parts as parameterized curves and surfaces in mathematica.