# Connected space being not locally connected at each point

Tags: gn.general-topology

Say that a topological space $X$ is **locally connected at some point $x$**, if it has a local base at that point consisting of connected open sets.
Also $X$ is **locally connected** if it is locally connected at each of its points.

It is well known that a connected space is not necessarily locally connected.

For example, let $X = \bigl([0;1] \times (\mathbb{Q}\cap[0;1])\bigr) \cup (0\times [0;1])$ be the union of horizontal segmets with rational $y$-coordinate together with a vertical segment intersecting all of them.
Then $X$ is connected but not locally connected.
Namely it is not locally connected at any point except for the points of that vertical segment $0\times[0;1]$.
On the other hand, it is still locally connected at each point of $0\times[0;1]$.

In fact, in all such examples which I know, connected spaces are still locally connected at some of their points.

> The question is to **construct an example of a connected space being not locally connected at any of its point**.

Probably this is also a standard example, but I never meet it.
I would be grateful for any information about that question.

Comment: The empty set is an example :) But of course the question is whether there's another one (and maybe you'd like Hausdorff too).

Comment: I would do this: let $\{q_i\}_{i\in\mathbb Z}$ a bijection  and take $X$ to be the quotient of $\mathbb Q\times [0,1]$ via $(q_i,1)\sim(q_{i+1},0)$

Comment: Also, a natural example is a dense orbit of a flow on a manifold (of dim≥2)

Comment: @YCor The empty set is not connected. It has zero connected components.

Comment: @ZhenLin It's a matter of convention. For instance the definition *"A space is connected if it equals the connected component of each of its points"* or *"if it cannot be made disjoint union of two nonempty open subsets"* (the latter is the Bourbaki definition) makes the empty set connected while *"is the connected component of one of its points"* makes it non-connected. I have no strong opinion what's the better convention.

Comment: Yes, but I am saying the other convention is misguided. It is analogous (in a way that can be made precise!) to how the zero ring is not a field or integral domain. The correct definition can be stated in category theoretic language: an object $X$ is connected if and only if, for every coproduct $\coprod_{i \in I} Y_i$ and every morphism $X \to \coprod_{i \in I} Y_i$, there is a unique $j \in I$ such that the morphism factors through $Y_j \to \coprod_{i \in I} Y_i$.

Answer (score 14):

There are compact groups that are connected, but not locally connected at any point. For instance, solenoids $(\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{Z}_p)/\langle (1,1)\rangle$. (It is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}\times$ Cantor.)

This is not path connected. A path-connected non-empty compact Hausdorff space that is not locally connected is given as follows: start from a Cantor subset $C$ of $[0,1]$ containing $0$, consider the product $C\times [0,2]$ and identify $(0,c)$ to $(c,2)$ for every $c\in C$.

[image: (Not very artistic) illustration]

Comment: I had in mind something similar but this is even better

Answer (score 9):

Here's a metric (and contractible) example, it is a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$. On each segment of the main zig-zagging line there's segments sticking out on a dense set, the idea is the same as the example you mention in the question body, but it is repeated to break local connectivity everywhere.

[image]

See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419732/examples-of-continua-that-are-contractible-but-are-not-locally-connected-at-any) for an (harder) example of a space which is compact, metric, connected and contractible, but not locally connected at any point.

Comment: Actually I first thought of this one and then "closed" it to make it compact.

Comment: @Ycor makes sense! I like this example because it is visually obvious that it works

Comment: I was going to suggest $$\{(n+t,mt):n\in\mathbb Z,t\in[0,1],m\in\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]\}$$ but your example is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

The [closed topologist's sine curve](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000114/properties) is the classic example of a connected but not locally connected space. But local neighborhoods away from the y-axis are copies of $\mathbb R$, which is connected.

To fix this, replace the copy of $(0,1]$ that waves toward the y-axis with a copy of $(0,1]\times 2^\omega$. The result is still connected as it's the union of many copies of the closed topologist's sine curve that intersect on the y-axis. But now local neighborhoods away from the y-axis are copies of $\mathbb R\times 2^\omega$, which is disconnected.